# Prove one program to be another's dual program

Tags: duality-theorems

This is the Primal problem

> $\min f_0(x)$,
>
> subject to $f_i(x) \leq 0$, i = $1,2,\ldots,m$
>
> $f(x)$ is a linear program

and my target is to prove that

> $\max g(λ)$
>
> subject to $\lambda \geq 0$
>
> where
>
> $g(λ) = \inf L(x, \lambda)$, which is the Lagrange dual function

is the dual program of the primal program.

I'm just confused how to do it, can anybody help me? thanks!